# Access an ODBC connection via an API

Tags: json, xml, windows, api, odbc

I want to write a web app that can extract data from a local server that makes its database available by ODBC. To that end, I want to run a lightweight service on the local server that makes the local ODBC connection available as an XML/JSON API over HTTPS. That way, my web app can easily fetch data from the local server.

Is there an easy way to achieve this without having to write a custom win32 service that runs on the local server?

Comment: Sure, just write it in .NET and run it in IIS, it's pretty easy to configure SSL that way and have lots of flexibility.

Comment: Write a ODBC->XML converter in .NET that lives on the local server you mean?

Surely there must be a drop in solution without having to write it? Surely I'm not the first person in the world that wants to publish an ODBC datasource as an XML API?

Comment: I've never seen anything, but I never look, since I write this kind of thing all the time.  Check out how to convert data sets to XML in .NET or ASP, it's one or two lines of code either way.